# Using slice.windows(2) including a final iteration of the last and first items

Tags: rust

I am implementing a function that takes a list of indices representing a solution to the traveling salesman problem, and calculate the total travel distance using a distance matrix.

I need to iterate over the list in windows of 2 and aggregate the distances, including a last iteration of traveling back from the last index in the list to the first one.

I'm trying to solve it in a functional-style way, my current solution is:

```
fn calculate_solution_distance(solution: Vec<usize>, distance_matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> i32 {
    [solution.as_slice(), &[solution[0]]]
        .concat()
        .windows(2)
        .map(|indices| get_distance(indices[0], indices[1], &distance_matrix))
        .sum()
}

fn get_distance(from: usize, to: usize, distance_matrix: &Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> i32 {
    distance_matrix[from][to]
}
```

This code works. however it seems rather inefficient, speficially creating a slice from the first index just so I can concat it with a slice of my list.
Is there a more efficient way to iterate over the list in windows of 2 such that the last item in the list is also iterated over twice?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference &String, &Vec, or &Box as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function) Your `calculate_solution_distance` doesn't need to take owned values either.

Comment: To prevent allocations, you should use a slice `&[Vec<i32>]` for the `distance_matrix` function argument in `get_distance()` instead of a `&Vec<Vec<i32>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Easily, just add the last pair:

```rust
fn calculate_solution_distance(solution: Vec<usize>, distance_matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> i32 {
    solution
        .windows(2)
        .chain(std::iter::once(
            &[solution[solution.len() - 1], solution[0]][..],
        ))
        .map(|indices| get_distance(indices[0], indices[1], &distance_matrix))
        .sum()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`Itertools::circular_tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.circular_tuple_windows) it uses Rust's std-offered [`Cycle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Cycle.html) and [`Take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Take.html) internally.

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    for (lhs, rhs) in a.iter().circular_tuple_windows() {
        dbg!((lhs, rhs));
    }
}
```